# Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed: NOT_FOUND: [AXONIQ-1302] default: not found in any replication group

Tags: java, spring, axon

I am trying to create basic example of SAGA with `AxonServer`

I am using `AxonServer-2023.1.2` :

```
2023-10-09 17:30:11.072  INFO 11540 --- [           main] io.axoniq.axonserver.AxonServer          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-10-09 17:30:14.683  INFO 11540 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8024 (http)
2023-10-09 17:30:14.843  INFO 11540 --- [           main] A.i.a.a.c.MessagingPlatformConfiguration : Configuration initialized with SSL DISABLED and access control DISABLED.
2023-10-09 17:30:15.814  WARN 11540 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "PUBLIC" may not be reproducible.
2023-10-09 17:30:17.626  INFO 11540 --- [           main] io.axoniq.axonserver.AxonServer          : Axon Server version 2023.1.2
2023-10-09 17:30:23.367  INFO 11540 --- [           main] i.a.a.e.c.i.MessagingClusterServer       : Axon Server Cluster Server started on port: 8224 - no SSL
2023-10-09 17:30:23.507  INFO 11540 --- [           main] io.axoniq.axonserver.grpc.Gateway        : Axon Server Gateway started on port: 8124 - no SSL
2023-10-09 17:30:23.520  INFO 11540 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8024 (http) with context path ''
2023-10-09 17:30:23.550  INFO 11540 --- [           main] io.axoniq.axonserver.AxonServer          : Started AxonServer in 13.045 seconds (JVM running for 13.932)
2023-10-09 17:30:30.296  INFO 11540 --- [nio-8024-exec-8] i.a.a.a.c.r.ContextAdminRequestProcessor : [<anonymous>] Request to list contexts.
```

I have empty spring-boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OrderServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrderServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

but im stuck with in loop on running the app:

```
i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Requesting connection details from localhost:8124
i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Connecting to AxonServer node [localhost:8124] failed: NOT_FOUND: [AXONIQ-1302] default: not found in any replication group
i.a.a.c.impl.AxonServerManagedChannel    : Failed to get connection to AxonServer. Scheduling a reconnect in 2000ms
```

I am using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.axonframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>axon-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

What is cuasing this? The console on webpage on port 8024 works fine, so why isnt the 8124 port working?

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi Johnyb. Not so much a reply to your Axon Server (@schananas his reply should help there), but I wanted to nudge you about the Axon Framework version. Axon Framework is currently on release 4.8.2, which has some tremendous improvements over 4.5. On of these is making the connection between Axon Framework and Axon Server more robust, for example. Thought you might want to know that!

Answer (score 1):

Try running Axon Server with following env property set:

```
AXONIQ_AXONSERVER_STANDALONE=true
```